# Pagination in two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables,

- `Orders` - this is small, typically up to 50 thousands records
- `OrdersArchive` - this one is normal, about 80 millions records

This situation might happens:

the order might have on of those values for `status`:

1. 'created'
2. 'processing'
3. 'finished'

The finished orders from `Orders` are periodically moved to `OrdersArchive`.

In other words, `Orders` might contain orders with status `created`, `processing` or `finished`. `OrdersArchive` contains only orders with a status of `finished`.

The result has to be sorted in this order 'created', 'processing', 'finished'

I need a query in this two tables which supports pagination.

What is the best way to do it? (so fast as possible)

A pagination might be any type

I mean like:

- the classical pagination with PageNumber and CountOfRowsPerPage.
- 'lazy' pagination with count of orders after the specific Order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the `union` SQL operator for this. See the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) page for details.

With union you can either do `union` or `union all`. The first will check for duplicates while the second just combines the results. It sounds like you shouldn't have duplicates in these two tables so for performance you don't need to do the distinct search.

You also need to make sure that both queries have the same number of columns with similar types.

e.g.

```
select orderno, status from Orders
union all
select orderno, status from OrdersArchive
order by status, orderno
```

**Pagination**
That query gives you the combined resultset for both tables. Now to add pagination I would use a CTE with row numbers like this:

```
with x as (
select orderno as num, status as stat from Orders
union all
select archiveorderno as num, archivestatus as stat from OrdersArchive
) select row_number() over(order by stat, num) as rownum, num, stat from x 
  where rownum between 1 and 20
```

**Alternative**
If you find using union is too slow then you could look at changing the way your search works. If you always sort the same way and it's always records from Orders followed by records from OrdersArchive then you could query the tables separately. Start by paging through Orders and then when you run out of records continue paging through OrdersArchive. This would be much faster than the union but you would have to keep the query simple and always sort on status. The union allows much more complex searches.

Answer (score 0):

Using OFFSET and FETCH NEXT in SQL Server can provide a paging solution. Rough sample code is:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 2
DECLARE @PageSize   INT = 100000;

SELECT [ID]
FROM [Table]
ORDER BY [ID]
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Obviously place in your own tables, filters, orders and probably put this in a stored procedure with the PageNumber and PageSize being input params